# How to map type of property to a constructor type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to map the type of a property to its corresponding constructor type, so `string` should become `StringConstructor`, `number` should bcome `NumberConstructor`...

This is what I got so far, but the intellisense shows `unknown` for both `test.name?.type` and `test.age?.type`

```
interface IPerson {
  name?: string
  age?: number
}

const test = {
  name: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number },
} as { [key in keyof IPerson]: {
  type: IPerson[key] extends string
    ? StringConstructor
    : IPerson[key] extends number
      ? NumberConstructor
      : unknown
}}
```

console.log(test.name?.type)
console.log(test.age?.type)

```
console.log(test.name?.type)
console.log(test.age?.type)
```

what do I need to change to map the `type` correctly?

URL to TypeScript REPL:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEETALZwDbIDeAUMsiHNhAFzIDOYUoA5qfcAF43kCu2ARtGIBfYsVCRYiFKgAK0OgHsQRNhSq0GTEKzJxmEAPy0QfQVDYAHCGGNpMOfCLFgAnteQBZOJesATABV3CAAeAIA+ZABeVTIAbQBpZFBkAGsIV0UYZACAXVoSMjI3a1oAxNzkCAAPSBA-OnpGFmQAH2QeeogYUAg-NiLkQ2QAZWadAGFlLR4EMEULQbIyiqraiHrG0wFoNo6unpA+gaXhgDkzaCmQGbmFk8GVhMqauobkRX4AKwg5h9OiMgABQASielVESyWJggADchGRRKJiAhpmAqlAoAtorFyJRuIRkCVuGNtMxkMIADRsfQEonBWgXHZQCnUsjWMAFemlZAAeW+v3RVOQAHoReQ4dBKRisVAAIQiZBwRreXx9ILWEJyBTKcJiVE3RR4CAAOjwimYQOgspN6lNxJBovFpJY11u8wsBqUxrNFqtmIWJtphhNDqdyCZ5jdjFmHpR0yNpvNlutgY5IbDYol8Kg0tT8v1aPIigAogGWTFCniNIDibQXTpWTSDFy6xHLiyqVYbK2GXyBXMlY1QdFIhgsLgCF3hEOvD5-BrQtqoEoQHr44afcmgSBS+XbfjQ8FHVmG8xo1BY-cvYnfZbd2WbcGj9YT+LI1c0Ze7p6E1u-Q++7pi+EBvsCjpRGODiTsQQA

Comment: Note that your `key` is a *type parameter* representing a keylike *type*; it is not a dummy key *name*.  So it is more conventional to name it like a type parameter (one or two uppercase characters like `K`, or at worst an uppercase type name like `Key`) instead of like a key name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) enabled, then the type of `name` and `age` properties of `IPerson` are not `string` and `number`; rather, they are `string | undefined` and `number | undefined`.  [Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) automatically have [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) added to their domain (if you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) this is a bit more complicated but it's still true that if you read an optional property it may include `undefined`).  And `string | undefined` does not extend `string`, so everything falls through to `unknown` and you are sad.

Perhaps the most expedient way of dealing with this is then to just test `extends string | undefined` instead of `extends string`, since `string extends string | undefined` is true:

```
const test: { [K in keyof IPerson]: {
  type: IPerson[K] extends string | undefined ? StringConstructor
  : IPerson[K] extends number | undefined ? NumberConstructor
  : unknown
} }
  = {
  name: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number },
};

/* const test: {
    name?: {
        type: StringConstructor;
    } | undefined;
    age?: {
        type: NumberConstructor;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

Note that there are more general solutions which will take a property of type `string | number` and turn it to a value of type `StringConstructor | NumberConstuctor`; that is, they will [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) your type operation over [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types); or solutions which will take a mapping type like `[string, StringConstructor] | [number, NumberConstructor] | ...` and use it to programmatically translate your types so that you can just add new elements like `[boolean, BooleanConstructor]` and it would work.  But all of these are out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't go into them for this question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMsiHALYQD8AXMlmFKAOYnJws30gCuFAI2hEAvkXEI8jZALgATACoRpAXkLtyVegWRgAngAcI9AMpNWyEQBp2nY4V2H7AOX5ColmyI5YHAbQBrCD1kUGQgvRwYNEwoXBAAXW12fSN6DGw8QOCE5AgAD0gQOV9GZhA2UmpkM3KWAGEpJl4EMBwodnTY+Oy9XIKikrI3YSrkV0FoRpAylraO0npeEACQHAB3EFFLCSbdZTBtZD8AaVD8CKiYzMTk0lT7DLisk-7CiGLS8wrkAB9kZZyCAwUAQOTIaq1VjTWatdqda7PECnN6DXx8SYef6A4Gg8HVCbuGHNOELZBLFZrTbbMSkNTEUiaew6B6mb4sTy2LhHVnjEYeayiADc4gA9AAqZCSGZgfaMO6kMiUbjqRVqxxpGrs4lQObtEVq7zY4q4kBgg2Kux0VXq+5OeiEqZNXWki2kI0Ak0gs1yEXecWi8REaW4AA2EAAdKGcCwABSQRgRpnUCMPACUwakOHDUZj8YOEatqacGaAA)

Comment: Adding `undefined` works fine. Using this approach I have troubles comparing against `object` however. Whenever I define `type: Object`, I want the typescript to enforce using a factory returning an instance of that object, e.g. `type: Object as () => IAnimal`. I created a new repro. As you can see `error.pet?.type` is still `() => IAnimal` instead of `never`. How can I fix this? (I updated the original REPL link

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing me there, sorry.  Are you turning off `--strictNullChecks` on purpose (and if so, why?)  Do you *want* `never` for some reason (and if so, why?).  You can use https://tsplay.dev to shorten playground links so you don't need to modify your question (which should probably stay the way it was before, since whoever clicks on that link will see something different from your question code).

Comment: So in my updated example, `IPerson` has a property `pet` that is of type `IAnimal`. In my object definition I want that to be enforced as `{ type: Object as () => IAnimal }`, as this is being used at runtime for validation. `{ type: Object }` should only be allowed, if the property type is `any`. If the property is not `string`, `number`, `boolean`, ... `any`, it should result in `() => IAnimal`.

Comment: So the problem seems to be, that `Object` is not restrictive enough for this use case. `const test: () => IAnimal = Object` works, so I'll have to find a way to make Object more restrictive, or make the `MappedType` type more specific instead of checking against `object`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that the types of `IPerson.name` and `IPerson.age` are both optional. So you can't test that the property extends string or number as it actually extends `(string | undefined)` and `(number | undefined)`. Thus your nested ternary is always going to evaluate to `unknown`.

To fix this you can change the interface of IPerson to have both properties required